# pyramid traversal resource url no attribute __name__

Tags: python, pyramid

So I have:

resources.py:

```
 def _add(obj, name, parent):
     obj.__name__ = name
     obj.__parent__ = parent
     return obj

 class Root(object):
     __parent__ = __name__ = None

     def __init__(self, request):
         super(Root, self).__init__()
         self.request = request
         self.collection = request.db.post

     def __getitem__(self, key):
         if u'profile' in key:
             return Profile(self.request)

 class Profile(dict):

     def __init__(self, request):
         super(Profile, self).__init__()
         self.__name__ = u'profile'
         self.__parent__ = Root
         self.collection = request.db.posts

     def __getitem__(self, name):
         post = Dummy(self.collection.find_one(dict(username=name)))
         return _add(post, name, self)
```

and I'm using MongoDB and `pyramid_mongodb`

views.py:

```
@view_config(context = Profile, renderer = 'templates/mytemplate.pt')
def test_view(request):
    return {}
```

and in mytemplate.pt:

```
 <p tal:repeat='item request.context'>
      ${item}
 </p>
```

I can echo what's in the database (I'm using mongodb), but when I provided a URL for each item using `resource_url()`

```
 <p tal:repeat='item request.context'>
 <a href='${request.resource_url(item)}'>${item}</a>
 </p>
```

I got an error: `'dict' object has no attribute '__name__'`, can someone help me?

Comment: FWIW in your paste, Profile has no use in being a `dict`. Also `Root.__getitem__` should raise a `KeyError` if nothing is matched instead of returning a context of `None`.

Comment: You may want to read the [blog post that appears to have been your starting point](http://kusut.web.id/2011/03/27/pyramid-traversal-and-mongodb/) in more detail. The author uses a `dict` subclass for a reason, one that you don't copy.

Comment: This is not the immediate cause of your problem, but `self.__parent__ = Root` line is wrong - `Root` is a *class*, ans you need an *instance* of that class. Pass a reference to your constructor: `def __init__(self, parent, request)`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Ya that blog is my starting point, and i apparently misunderstood the code given. I thought when we want to print some data that is assigned to an object, we use `__getitem__` method, it turns out we should use `__iter__` method

Answer (score 2):

Well a full traceback would sure be useful. However in your example I can at least say that `self.__parent__ = Root` needs to be using the actual object, and not the class.